# Managing shared libraries in GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish, shared-libraries, glassfish-3

What my question is all war files deployed in Glassfish are using same code base but with different database names , so libraries used in all  war files are same.

1)Can Glassfish have shared lib folder similar to tomcat, if yes need steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glassfish has shared libraris too, just copy your libraries in one of following directories and restart Glassfish.

- glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib : which will share libraries across all applications deployed to domain1
- glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish\lib : which will share libraries across all applications deployed to all domains.