# Errors while deploying an enterprise application on glassfish's admin console

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I created an enterprise application using session Beans, Data Assess Object(DAO) and a remote interface embeded in a java class library, and a .war file as the application client, when I deploy it on Netbeans IDE it works fine and deploys.  However, when I undeploy it and try to deploy it through uploading the .ear file in the Glassfish's admin console panel it give me the error:

```
 SEVERE: LDR5203: An error occurred while adding URL   [file:/C:/Users/MACDONALD/.netbeans/7.1.2/config/GF3/domain1/applications/Jerger/lib/Jergli    b.jar] to the 
EJB class loader. Please check the content of this URL. 
SEVERE: LDR5200:MalformedURLException.
java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty   
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)    
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)   
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)   
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:152)   
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:116)   
at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader$ProtectedJarFile.<init>  (ASURLClassLoader.java:913)  
at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader$URLEntry.init(ASURLClassLoader.java:980)  
at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader$URLEntry.<init>(ASURLClassLoader.java:971)    
at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.appendURL(ASURLClassLoader.java:298)  
at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.addURL(ASURLClassLoader.java:280) 
at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarLibClassLoader.<init>(EarLibClassLoader.java:57) 
at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarHandler$1.run(EarHandler.java:333)   
at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarHandler$1.run(EarHandler.java:330)   
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   
at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarHandler.getClassLoader(EarHandler.java:330)  
at   org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:218)    
at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentContextImpl.createDeploymentClassLoader(DeploymentContextImpl.java:199)    
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:346)  
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)  
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)  
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)  
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)  
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)  
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)  
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)  
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)    
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) 
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) 
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)    
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) 
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)  
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)  
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)  
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) 
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)   
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)   
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)    
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)    
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)    
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147) 
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)   
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)   
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)   
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)    
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849) 
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746) 
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)  
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)   
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)  
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)   
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)    
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)    
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)    
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) 
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)   
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
WARNING: DPL8004: file open failure; file =    file:/C:/Users/MACDONALD/.netbeans/7.1.2/config/GF3/domain1/applications/Jerger/lib/Jerglib    .jar
WARNING: zip file is empty --  invalid zip file:     file:/C:/Users/MACDONALD/.netbeans/7.1.2/config/GF3/domain1/applications/Jerger/lib/Jerglib    .jar
WARNING: DPL8004: file open failure; file =    file:/C:/Users/MACDONALD/.netbeans/7.1.2/config/GF3/domain1/applications/Jerger/lib/Jerglib    .jar
WARNING: zip file is empty --  invalid zip file:    file:/C:/Users/MACDONALD/.netbeans/7.1.2/config/GF3/domain1/applications/Jerger/lib/Jerglib    .jar
SEVERE: Exception while parsing file f   file:/C:/Users/MACDONALD/.netbeans/7.1.2/config/GF3/domain1/applications/Jerger/lib/Jerglib    .jar
java.lang.NullPointerException  
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$ArchiveJarEntrySource.  <init>(InputJarArchive.java:573) 
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$ArchiveJarEntrySource.<init>(InputJarArchive.java:565)   
at   com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.createEntryEnumeration(InputJarArchive.java:443)   
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.entries(InputJarArchive.java:196)    
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.entries(InputJarArchive.java:175)    
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:128) 
at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:348)   
at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:70)   
at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:307)   
at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:296)  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)   
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)  
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
WARNING: DPL8004: file open failure; file =   file:/C:/Users/MACDONALD/.netbeans/7.1.2/config/GF3/domain1/applications/Jerger/lib/Jerglib    .jar
WARNING: zip file is empty --  invalid zip file: file:/C:/Users/MACDONALD/.netbeans/7.1.2/config/GF3/domain1/applications/Jerger/lib/Jerglib    .jar
WARNING: DPL8004: file open failure; file = file:/C:/Users/MACDONALD/.netbeans/7.1.2/config/GF3/domain1/applications/Jerger/lib/Jerglib    .jar
WARNING: zip file is empty --  invalid zip file: file:/C:/Users/MACDONALD/.netbeans/7.1.2/config/GF3/domain1/applications/Jerger/lib/Jerglib    .jar
SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [Jerger]
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException  
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$ArchiveJarEntrySource.<init>(InputJarArchive.java:573)   
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$ArchiveJarEntrySource.<init>(InputJarArchive.java:565)   
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.createEntryEnumeration(InputJarArchive.java:443) 
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.entries(InputJarArchive.java:196)    
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.access$100(InputJarArchive.java:73)  
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$1.enumeration(InputJarArchive.java:159)  
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive$CollectionWrappedEnumeration.<init>(InputJarArchive.java:716)    
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.InputJarArchive.getDirectories(InputJarArchive.java:154) 
at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentUtils.isEARFromIntrospecting(DeploymentUtils.java:338) 
at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentUtils.isEAR(DeploymentUtils.java:326)  
at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentUtils.hasResourcesXML(DeploymentUtils.java:255)
at org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentUtils.hasResourcesXML(DeploymentUtils.java:268)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.connector.module.ResourcesCompositeSniffer.handles(ResourcesCompositeSniffer.java:77)  
at org.glassfish.internal.deployment.GenericCompositeSniffer.handles(GenericCompositeSniffer.java:80)   
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.SnifferManagerImpl.getCompositeSniffers(SnifferManagerImpl.java:190)    
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:603) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)  
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)  
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)  
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)  
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)  
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)  
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)  
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)  
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)    
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) 
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) 
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)    
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) 
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)  
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)  
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)  
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) 
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)   
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)   
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)    
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)    
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)    
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147) 
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)   
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)   
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)   
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)    
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849) 
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746) 
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)  
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)   
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)  
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)   
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)    
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)    
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)    
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) 
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)   
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [Jerger]
INFO: Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying   the app [Jerger]. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Can someone tell me what could be the problem, it works fine when I deployed with Netbeans IDE but doesn't when I try this way.

Answer (score 0):

you have probably "linked" and not copied the library "Jerglib.jar" during development. You have to add the library to you proyect, because the server is trying to get the library from a location in the hard drive where the server cannot have access. Check your developing environtment and copy the libraries to your proyect instead of linking them.

In NetBeans, for example, it is done in a very easy way, check the following question:

[Java, How to add library files in netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893349/how-to-add-library-files-in-netbeans)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i added the "jerlib.jar" file to the project it deployed successfully from netbeans but i couldn't deploy it directly from the glassfish admin console

Comment: Maybe you have to put the library in some specific path, check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889545/where-to-put-external-libs-in-glassfish